# How to get group duration timing in K6

Tags: reporting, k6

I am using k6 versions k6 v0.43.1 ((devel), go1.20.1, darwin/amd64) on Mac OS ventura 13.2.1, and my requirement is to get the group timining for the request. I was trying this sample script

````
import http from 'k6/http';

export default function () {
  group('my-group', function () {
    http.get('https://test.k6.io');
    console.log(group.duration('my-group'));
  });
}```
but everytime getting either ''TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined" error or “TypeError: Object has no member ‘duration’”

Please help.
````

Answer (score 1):

[`group`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6/group/) is a function which enables you to [organize your test scripts](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/tags-and-groups/#groups) and automatically records metrics. Metrics are tagged with `group` with the group's name as value. Nesting groups separates their group names with `::`.

You cannot read the duration of a single group execution in your script directly.

If you need the duration metrics for a specific group, add them to your threshold definitions:

```
import { group } from 'k6';
import http from 'k6/http';

export const options = {
    thresholds: {
        'group_duration{group:::my-group}': [],
    },
};

export default function () {
  group('my-group', function () {
    http.get('https://test.k6.io');
  });
}
```

This will print the following line(s) in your end-of-test summary:

```
 group_duration.................: avg=363.79ms min=363.79ms med=363.79ms max=363.79ms p(90)=363.79ms p(95)=363.79ms
   { group:::my-group }.........: avg=363.79ms min=363.79ms med=363.79ms max=363.79ms p(90)=363.79ms p(95)=363.79ms
```

If you really need the live duration of a single code path, you must measure the time yourself:

```
export default function() {
  const start = Date.now();
  // ... your logic here ...
  const duration = Date.now() - start;
  console.log(`Duration: ${duration}`);
}
```

Of course it is entirely possible to define your own custom function to simplify taking such measurements:

```
function measure(fn) {
  const start = Date.now();
  fn(); // optionally wrap in a group here
  return Date.now() - start;
}

export default function() {
  const duration = measure(function () {
    http.get('https://test.k6.io');
  });
  console.log(`Duration: ${duration}`);
}
```